# Creating a ticket in Freshdesk from Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to write some code that submits a ticket automatically with information from a page I created in Apps Script. I have tried numerous examples, but I can't seem to get my code to work.

```
 var headers = {
'Content-type': 'application/json',
'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(API_KEY + ':X')
};

//Puts together the ticket according to the freshdesk api.  
//var payload = '{"helpdesk_ticket":{"description":"' + message + '","subject":"' + subject + '","email":"' + arr[0][0] + '","priority":"' + ticketPriority + '","status":2}}'; 
//var payload = '{"helpdesk_ticket":{"description": message ,"subject": subject,"email": arr[0][0],"priority": ticketPriority,"status":2}}';

var payload = '{"helpdesk_ticket":{"description":"TEST","subject":"TEST","email":"test@test.com","priority":1,"status":2}}';

//Adds the extensions that are needed to post a new ticket to the end of the url
var url = ENDPOINT + '/helpdesk/tickets.json';

var options = {
'method': 'post',
'headers': headers,
'payload': payload,
muteHttpExceptions: true
};

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

This is what I currently have. I have gotten it to work once, but only when I do not have any variables being assigned to the 'description' or 'subject' header (the line with the payload variables that is uncommented. When I use that line, a ticket is successfully created). I am not sure why my first or second lines with the payload variables would not work. The variable 'message' is just a String with some new line characters '\n' in it. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: Instead of building the payload as a string. Build it as an object and JSON.stringify it. Do you get the same results?

Comment: I solved this by building the message variable with HTML code and using the 'description_html' property instead of 'description'

Answer (score 0):

Solved by building the message variable with HTML code and using the 'description_html' property instead of 'description'.